# Accessing remote shell of a pod as root user

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, containers, openshift

I created a Jenkins persistent app using this template [here](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/jenkins/jenkins-persistent-template.json). Now when a pod gets created and I want to access pod as a root user. But when I do `oc rsh jenkins-mypod`, it opens the pod as a `default` user. I want to open the pod as the `root` user. How can I do that?. I created this app under the `developer` account.

Comment: you can try using `runasuser` attribute (not sure if is applicable in your case) . security related stuff is discussed at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/

Comment: can you please edit the template that I mentioned. I'm new to k8 and really not getting what to change.

Comment: did you try `sudo su` after rsh btw?

Comment: @MaxLobur yes!
After `oc rsh jenkins-mypod` I did 
`sh-4.2$ sudo ` and it asked for a password but I didn't set up any password.

Comment: Maybe change Jenkins docker image to allow `sudo nopasswd`

Answer (score 2):

This is an opened issue in kubernetes https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30656 so I don't think it's possible in openshift either.

Answer (score 1):

This will work `oc rsh --as root` if you have access to impersonate resource "users" in API group "" at the cluster scope.

Comment: rsh `--as` option means to impersonate another user, from openshift API point of view. In theory, there is no way to change your user id on an unprivileged container.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "kubectl ssh" plugin from here: https://github.com/jordanwilson230/kubectl-plugins

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third-party tool [kubectl-exec-user](https://github.com/mikelorant/kubectl-exec-user) to achieve this. It does not require allowing `sudo` or any other privilege escalation mechanism in the container.

There is [currently no built-in solution](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30656).

Comment: does this plugin also work on OCP with CONTAINER-RUNTIME: cri-o ?